# CSS positioning issues bootstrap

Tags: css

I am working with a slider with caption text from *bootstrap*. I am also trying to match the style as the design I added bellow. But I can't move the caption part on the left as design says. I have used CSS position property, but It does not work. I want to move the caption part to the left of the image like the design. Sorry to say that I can not put my sample code as a link in here.

**Requirement is the caption text should slide with the image of the right position.

**Design example:**
[image: PSD Design]

Sample code I have created to test: `jsfiddle.net/px5khf89/3/embedded/result/`

```css
.body-area-one {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/*body-area-one-left*/

.body-area-one-left,
.body-area-one-right {
  padding: 0;
}
.body-area-one-left {
  position: relative;
}
.body-area-one-left img {
  width: 100%;
}
.inner-part {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px dashed #ded4c9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 70%;
}
.inner-part .control-padd {
  padding: 8px;
}
.inner-part h3 {
  color: #7d7c78;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.inner-part p {
  color: #7d7c78;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
}
.inner-part a,
.footer-top .middle-bottom a,
.contact-area .contact-area-inner .textarea-right input[type="submit"] {
  background: url(../img/link-bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.inner-part a {
  float: right;
}
.body-area-one-left .carousel-inner {
  color: #959595;
  font-size: 20px;
}
/*body-area-one-right*/

.body-area-one-right .carousel-indicators {
  bottom: -10px;
}
.body-area-one-right .carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 1px;
}
.body-area-one-right .carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: #ADAEAD;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="custom-width">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="body-area-one">
            <div class="col-md-9 body-area-one-left">
              <img alt="gast" class="img-responsive" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/121936941/sh%20pic/gast.png">
            </div>
            <!-- end body-area-one-left-->
            <div class="col-md-3 body-area-one-right">
              <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="first-carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#first-carousel"></li>
                  <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#first-carousel"></li>
                  <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#first-carousel"></li>
                  <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#first-carousel"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <div class="inner-part">
                      <div class="control-padd">
                        <h3>Kindercollectie</h3>

                        <p>Naast de reguliere kinderschoenen merken hebben we ook stoere en gave modellen van Nike , Cruyff en All Stars in ons assortiment voor diegene die niet alleen voor de pasvorm willen gaan maar die toch een goed passende vlotte schoen
                          willen hebben.
                        </p>
                      </div><a href="#">Bekijk Kindermodellen »</a>

                    </div>
                    <img alt="slider-img1" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/121936941/sh%20pic/slider-img1.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="inner-part">
                      <div class="control-padd">
                        <h3>Kindercollectie</h3>

                        <p>Naast de reguliere kinderschoenen merken hebben we ook stoere en gave modellen van Nike , Cruyff en All Stars in ons assortiment voor diegene die niet alleen voor de pasvorm willen gaan maar die toch een goed passende vlotte schoen
                          willen hebben.
                        </p>
                      </div><a href="#">Bekijk Kindermodellen »</a>

                    </div>
                    <img alt="slider-img1" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/121936941/sh%20pic/slider-img1.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="inner-part">
                      <div class="control-padd">
                        <h3>Kindercollectie</h3>

                        <p>Naast de reguliere kinderschoenen merken hebben we ook stoere en gave modellen van Nike , Cruyff en All Stars in ons assortiment voor diegene die niet alleen voor de pasvorm willen gaan maar die toch een goed passende vlotte schoen
                          willen hebben.
                        </p>
                      </div><a href="#">Bekijk Kindermodellen »</a>

                    </div>
                    <img alt="slider-img1" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/121936941/sh%20pic/slider-img1.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="inner-part">
                      <div class="control-padd">
                        <h3>Kindercollectie</h3>

                        <p>Naast de reguliere kinderschoenen merken hebben we ook stoere en gave modellen van Nike , Cruyff en All Stars in ons assortiment voor diegene die niet alleen voor de pasvorm willen gaan maar die toch een goed passende vlotte schoen
                          willen hebben.
                        </p>
                      </div><a href="#">Bekijk Kindermodellen »</a>

                    </div>
                    <img alt="slider-img1" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/121936941/sh%20pic/slider-img1.png">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- end body-area-one-right-->
            </div>
            <!-- end body-area-one-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: please add your code in your question instead of just "linking" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed to some extent, although you would have to make some adjustments to the images.

```
jsfiddle.net/px5khf89/9/
```

Comment: It's working fine. I'll make the rest of the task myself. Thanks dude. You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
    media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-9 {
float: right;
width: 75%;
}
```

Use this and you text will move to left

Comment: It does not work what you are saying. Can you check the code again?